# Parking symbol (blue square P) in iOS 10 / macOS Sierra won't render as emoji?

Tags: utf-8, emoji, ios10, macos-sierra

Does anyone know how to get the "blue square P" emoji to render using UTF-8 in macOS Sierra and iOS 10 or later?

It's the only emoji I've found that reverts to its flat Unicode format in these latest (at this time of writing iOS and macOS updates): For me, this is just a P in a black square:

The emoji I'm talking about: http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%85%BF

I've tried every UTF-8 variant of this I can find, but it seems only UTF-16 works now to make it render as emoji and not flat unicode.

Can anyone confirm whether there's a way to get this to render as the blue-squared "P" using UTF-8 now? If there is a way, please share a byte string! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution I've found so far:

[image: temporary solution]

**It's the only emoji I've found that does this...** and it only does it in macOS Sierra and iOS 10. Older versions don't have the inconsistency.